# PubSub "Connection reset by peer" on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-dotnet-client

I encountered the exception.

> "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.HandleRpcFailure(Exception e)\n   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.HandlePullMoveNext(Task initTask)\n   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SubscriberClientImpl.SingleChannel.StartAsync()\n   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.ForwardingAwaiter.GetResult()\n   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<g__Inner|0>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n

"Invoke" function was executed to pull a message from my topic **per 5 seconds** in the scheduler

```cs
public async Task Invoke()
{
  var subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(CreateSubscriptionName());
   await subscriber.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
   {
      
      //.... 
      return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
   });
   await subscriber.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

How did I fix this ?

Thanks!

I've already checked the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/latest/index#coding-considerations)

> PublisherClient and SubscriberClient are expensive to create, so when regularly publishing or subscribing to the same topic or subscription then a singleton client instance should be created and used for the lifetime of the application.

But I still don't know how to do ...
I guessed I left too many open connections ?

Comment: Related [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/5889)

Comment: I adjusted ClientCount to 1 and check whether it has the same exception as before.

Comment: UPDATE: After I added, it still happened ...

Comment: UPDATE: It worked. I used DI to solve it.